# Why do nether portals sometimes not work for me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Sometimes I walk into a Nether portal and it doesn't work. The screen gets all wavy, and then nothing happens. It just stays wavy. I don't change dimensions. This happens both ways, Nether to Overworld and Overworld to Nether.

I do not have Multiverse installed.

This occurs sometimes after I have just used the portal, and other times when I have not used a portal in a considerably long time.

I'm fairly sure this problem has *something* to do with my player.dat file, as removing the file and allowing the server to generate another fixes the issue temporarily.

Comment: Is this after coming back from the Nether/overworld?

Comment: Can you just move out of the portal and attempt to move back in and then get transported?

Comment: @Ender They're suspecting that you're encountering the cooldown timer. So, to be more clear, there is a cooldown timer: if you're only experiencing this not-working effect soon after using a portal (so, going through, and then turning around and trying to go back through again), that's by design. They're trying to eliminate that possibility, to better answer the question.

Comment: Where can I find information on this 'cooldown timer'?

Comment: The wiki page on Nether portals mentions it obliquely when it says mobs' 30s cooldown timer is longer than the player's, but fails to actually say how long it is.

Comment: Regarding your edit: no. Also, it's bad form to use an edit to fundamentally change the question.

Comment: @Sevensideddie really? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7671/is-it-ok-to-edit-a-question-to-the-point-that-it-is-no-longer-the-same-question

Comment: @Ender Yes, really. This question hasn't been closed as off-topic or similar, so that meta isn't relevant. An question shouldn't switch what it's asking unless what it's asking isn't on topic and switching would fix that. This is on topic, so switching isn't required to fix topicality. Changing the central question to ask if a guess is correct definitely doesn't work. If you want to ask a related but different question, that's best as a separate but related question.

Comment: Does it work if you don't have Bukkit installed and instead use the vanilla server jar rather than MCPC/ForgeBukkit/whatever you're using for Bukkit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some players can't craft iron tools](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133403/some-players-cant-craft-iron-tools)

Comment: This is a duplicate because both questions deal with bukkit bugs and my answer to the linked question also answers this question.

Comment: @Ender Answer doesn't matter when deciding whether the question is a dupe or not.

Comment: Yes it does, it's what determines if a questions is a dupe or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my plugins were bugged. I had to delete and reinstall all my plugins and their configs to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it worked when I stood in the doorway and waited to be transported instead of walking through.

Answer (score -1):

It would be because of lag. Try exiting and then entering your world again.

Comment: Why would lag prevent entering the portal?

Comment: Re-entering the world does not fix it.

Comment: @Ender - Having a lot of lag prevents you from entering the Nether. This is mostly found on servers but can be found in singleplayer. This does not always happen but could be a possible answer.