# Some players can't craft iron tools

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I can make iron tools on my Craftbukkit server with my account, but there are three other accounts that cannot.

This is an image from another player's account; notice no shovel appears:

[image: Crafting GUI containing shovel recipe but with no shovel output]

Things I've tried without success:

1. Stop/start server
2. Reboot server
3. Disable all Bukkit plugins
4. Downgrade from the latest 1.6.4 developmental build to 1.6.2
5. Make the player an "op"
6. Have player login from my computer (and vice versa).  I can create iron objects.  He cannot.

On the same hosting service I launched a Vanilla 1.6.4 server, and that works: all accounts can create iron tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When bukkit plugins bug, the bug is somehow linked to the configs. If you disable them, and re-enable them, it doesn't fix the problem. You have to completely uninstall the plugins, and delete all the associated files, including the configs, then reinstall everything from scratch.